# Can running a Maven command (in Git Bash) affect a process already running in Intellij IDE?

Tags: spring, git, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am developing a Spring application. I am able to run my app in DEV mode from Intellij without any issues. Then, if I try to deploy my app (backend & frontend) using Git Bash, my Spring backend (DEV mode) crashes in Intellij giving FileNotFoundException (different/random file each time). The deployed mode builds without errors.

I have tried the same thing multiple times along with restarting my workstation and restarting/updating Intellij.

Here is the error message I am getting in Intellij for the backend DEV mode process.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.solu.DevelopmentApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/solu/domain/DataTransferService.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.solu.DevelopmentApplication.main(DevelopmentApplication.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/solu/domain/DataTransferService.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:75)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:685)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:375)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:323)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:191)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:295)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What command do you run in git bash?

Comment: @CrazyCoder It is part of a (much) bigger script that deploys the app (all micro-services) on my local Tomcat server.

Comment: Without knowing what exactly your script is doing it's impossible to answer your question. Also, your question already has the answer. Yes, it can affect it. Like when your script changes or deletes class or resource files in the build directory while the app is still running.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I will get back to you with the exact command that causes this issue. But in general, one would assume that these 2 things (running something in Git Bash and running something in IntelliJ) would be independent of each other. Is it possible in any scenario where they could affect each other?

Comment: Yes, if the build target folders are shared between IntelliJ IDEA and Maven, it could be the case.